# Akka HTTP in android studio import error - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, akka-http

I'm trying to use Akka-HTTP-client library instead of Retrofit. but I can't import the dependency and got Build error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 5 files found with path 'reference.conf' from inputs:
      - /home/vasanth/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http_2.13/10.2.6/e67c00fd41067c8c268748ffebe1ece40dab5984/akka-http_2.13-10.2.6.jar
      - /home/vasanth/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-core_2.13/10.2.6/a95560123b64a592e5b5340cc52e41371ee6f6b1/akka-http-core_2.13-10.2.6.jar
      - /home/vasanth/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream_2.13/2.6.16/3ec252797aa7d552d0c710e088e5cf6e081f4905/akka-stream_2.13-2.6.16.jar
      - /home/vasanth/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.13/2.6.16/37db3d5089e75b685c839e72a216775eae07331a/akka-actor_2.13-2.6.16.jar
      - /home/vasanth/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe/ssl-config-core_2.13/0.4.2/93eaf36919de5cfa68f39874c1829faba2a66e4b/ssl-config-core_2.13-0.4.2.jar
     Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
     https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.3/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
     for more information

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

and my app level build.gradle is

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.13:10.2.6'
    implementation 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-http_2.13:10.2.6'
    implementation 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.13:2.6.16'
    implementation 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.13:2.6.16'
}
```

can somebody help me to solve the issue
*Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.*? and please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

simple, After merging the reference.conf files the error was solved.
added the following code in my *build.gradle*

```
android.packagingOptions.resources.merges += "**/reference.conf"
```